# "a cold yesterday" or "a cold day yesterday"

Tags: word-order, phrase-choice

> It was such a cold yesterday that we could not go out.
>
> It was such a cold **day** yesterday that we could not go out.

Which sentence is grammatical or better?

Comment: The first, *cold **day** yesterday*, is natural; the second is not idiomatic.

Comment: *Yesterday* is commonly used adverbially. So it'll be weird if the *cold* modify it. But I think both of them are grammatical.

Comment: The second is not something speakers would typically say, any more than they would say "It is such *a hot today*". We would say "It's such a hot day today".   Using *today* and *yesterday* and *tomorrow* as nouns is certainly possible in the proper contexts, but using them as nouns here in this context would be very unnatural.  It might be possible in a literary context, say, but it's not what you would hear on the street.

Comment: Is"a cold day yesterday"  appositive structure?

Comment: Not strictly an appositive since "yesterday" is not a noun there, but a temporal adposition.

Comment: You can think of *yesterday* as meaning "*on* the day before (this day)" and *tomorrow* as meaning "on the morrow". These are not simple nouns, like *day*, but *prepositional phrases* that have been squeezed together, so to speak, into something that looks like a single word; each is actually several words. That squeezing is an orthographic artefact.

Answer (score 1):

Usually to say that the day before today was cold, one might use

> It was such *a cold day yesterday* that we could not go out.
>   It was *so cold yesterday*, we could not go out.

to say

> It was such *a cold yesterday* that we could not go out.

is not correct and may not be understandable since the listener may be wondering *which* yesterday, however, it might be possible to use

> It was *a cold yesterday*

in a poetic sense to describe a cold day in the past.  For example,

> It was a cold day.

the listener would be able to imagine themself being in the fictional day, whereas

> It was a cold yesterday.

the listener might only be able to imagine themself *after* the described day, using "yesterday" making it further in the past.